# Javascript prototypíng and ''this'' of instantiated object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

here's a tricky one. I create a class...

```
App = function(o) {

    var _app = this;

    this.events = {
        listeners : {
            list : new Array(),
            add : function(event, fn) {
                if (! this.list[event]) this.list[event] = new Array();
                if (!(fn in this.list[event]) && fn instanceof Function) this.list[event].push(fn);
                if (_app.debug.get()) _app.events.dispatch('log.append','EVENTS:ADD:'+event);
            },
            remove : function(event, fn) {
                if (! this.list[event]) return;
                for (var i=0, l=this.list[event].length; i<l; i++) {
                    if (this.list[event][i] === fn) {
                        if (_app.debug.get()) _app.events.dispatch('log.append','EVENTS:REMOVE:'+event);
                        this.list[event].slice(i,1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        dispatch : function(event, params) {
            if (! this.listeners.list[event]) return;
            for (var i=0, l=this.listeners.list[event].length; i<l; i++) {
                if (_app.debug.get()) _app.events.dispatch('log.append','EVENTS:DISPATCH:'+event);
                this.listeners.list[event][i].call(window, params);
            }
        }
    };

};
```

and prototype more functionality later. Here's one;

```
App.prototype.connection = {

    source : { 'default' : null },
    types : new Array(),
    pool : new Array(),
    count : function() { return this.pool.length },
    active : {
        pool : new Array(),
        count : function() { return this.pool.length },
        add : function(o) { this.pool.push(o) },
        remove : function(o) { this.pool.splice(this.pool.indexOf(o), 1); }
    },
    create : function(o) {
        if (! o || ! o.exe) o.exe = this.source.default;
        if (! o || ! o.type) o.type = 'xhr';
        var c = new this.types[o.type];
        App.events.dispatch('connection.created',c);
        this.pool.push(c);
        return c;
    },
    remove : function(o) {
        App.events.dispatch('connection.removed',o);
        this.pool.splice(this.pool.indexOf(o), 1);
    },
    abort : function(o) {
        var i = this.pool.indexOf(o);
        if (i===-1) return;
        this.pool[i].abort();
    }

};
```

then instantiate this into an object.

```
app = new App();
```

The problem is, I have a line called App.events.dispatch('connection.removed',o) which doesn't work. App needs to be the instantiation 'app' which ideally would be 'this', but this refers to App.prototype.connection. How do you get at the root in this case?

Thanks - Andrew

Comment: `this.events.dispatch('connection.removed',o);` does not work ? I feel like it should

Comment: Just saying, `list : new Array()`, should be `list: {}`.

Comment: @Joucks, No, `this` will be the `connection` object.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You should read the code again. Push is not called on the main `list`, it's called on `this.list[event]`, which should be an array.

Comment: @plalx fair enough, my bad.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Please update us on progress

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the object literal approach to define the `connection` on the `prototype`, otherwise there's no way to access the `App` instance.

Note that when you are referencing `App`, you are referencing the constructor function, not the `App` instance. Also, `this` inside `create` for instance would not be working because `this` will point to the `connection` object, not the `App` instance either.

There are a few options:

```
function Connection(eventBus) {
    this.eventBus = eventBus;
}

Connection.prototype = {
    someFunction: function () {
        this.eventBus.dispatch(...);
    }
};

function App() {
    // this.events = ...

    //the instance could also be injected, but you would need to implement
    //a setEventBus on the connection object, or simply do conn.eventBus = this;
    this.connection = new Connection(this);
}

var App = new App();
```

Also, please note that all mutable values (e.g. objects) defined on the `prototype` will be shared across **all** instances. That's probably not what you want.

Also note that:

```
 listeners : {
     list : new Array()
```

Should be:

```
 listeners : {
     list : {}
```

An array is meant to have `numeric` indexes only, while a plain object is a better structure to use as a map.